# Prove that if $a^x = b^y = (ab)^{xy}$, then $x + y = 1$

Tags: logarithms

The question is prove that if $a^x = b^y = (ab)^{xy}$, then

$$x + y = 1$$

I've tried:

$$a^x = (ab)^{xy}$$
$$\log_aa^x = \log_a(ab)^{xy}$$
$$x = xy \log_ab $$
$$y^{-1} = \log_ab$$

but then I get stuck and I'm not sure if this is the right path. What is an elegant solution please?

Comment: I don't understand, what if $x = y = 0$?

Comment: I don't understand either, what if $a=1$ or $b=1$ or $a=b=0$?

Comment: You must specify that a and b are not equal to zero or one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method** $1:$

$a^x=b^y=(ab)^{xy}=c$(say)

Taking logarithm to the base $c,$

$$x\log_ca=y\log_cb=xy\left(\log_ca+\log_cb\right)=1$$ as $\log ab=\log a+\log b$

$\implies \log_ca=\frac1x,\log_cb=\frac1y$ (consider when $\log_ca,\log_cb$ will be finite & defined)

Put values of $\log_ca,\log_cb$ in  $$xy\left(\log_ca+\log_cb\right)=1$$

**Method** $2:$

Taking logarithm to the base $a,$  in $a^x=b^y=(ab)^{xy}$

$$x=y\log_ab=xy(\log_aab)=xy(\log_aa+\log_ab)=xy(1+\log_ab)$$

From $x=y\log_ab, \log_ab=\frac xy \ \ \ \ (1)$

From $x=xy(1+\log_ab)$

Case $1:$ If $x\ne0, 1=y(1+\log_ab)\iff \log_ab=\frac1y-1  \ \ \ \ (2)$

Equate the values $\log_ab$ from $(1),(2)$

Case $2:$ If $x=0,$ the problem reduces to $1=b^y=1$

Can you take it from here?

**Method** $3:$

From, $a^x=(ab)^{xy}=a^{xy}b^{xy}\implies a^{x(1-y)}=b^{xy}\ \ \ \ (1)$

Similarly, $b^y=(ab)^{xy}=a^{xy}b^{xy}\implies b^{y(1-x)}=a^{xy}\ \ \ \ (2)$

As lcm of the powers of $b$ is lcm$(xy,y(1-x))=xy(1-x)$

From $(1), b^{x(1-x)y}=(b^{xy})^{1-x}=(a^{x(1-y)})^{1-x}=a^{x(1-x)(1-y)}$

From $(2), b^{x(1-x)y}=(b^{y(1-x)})^x=(a^{xy})^x=a^{x^2y}$

Comparing the values of  $b^{x(1-x)y},$   we get $a^{x^2y}=a^{x(1-x)(1-y)}$

What can we say if $a^m=a^n?$

Comment: The first two methods are great, thanks. How does the third method work after the second line though? I follow the first two lines of it but then lose understanding after you mention the lowest common multiple "of the powers of y is..."

Comment: @GezBishop, sorry for the typo. It should be 'As lcm of the powers of $b$ ...'

Comment: What if you attempted it with natural log? Might make it more neater.

Answer (score 2):

let  us take logarithm of both side,we have
$x\log(a)=y\log(b)=xy(\log(a)+\log(b))$

or  $x\log(a)-xy(\log(a)=xy\log(b)-y\log(b)$

could you continue?

or we could rearrange  otherwise

$x\log(a)-\log(b)=y(x\log(a)-\log(b)$

$y=1$   or we should have  $x\log(a)-\log(b)=0$
when we put  $y=1$ into  $b^y=(ab)^{xy}$

$b=(ab)^{x}$  from where  $x=0$ and  $b=1$

Answer (score 0):

## **Solution with natural logs**:

### $a^x=b^y=(ab)^{xy}$

Take natural logs of everything,

$$ln(a^x) = ln(b^y) = ln((ab)^{xy})$$

**Create an equation for $x$ with no $y$:**

Use log laws to bring down the power,

$yln(b)= xyln(ab)$

Divide by $y$ on both sides,

$ln(b) = xln(ab)$

Expand the natural log on the RHS,

$ln(b) = x(ln(a) + ln(b))$

Make $x$ the subject,

### $x = \frac{ln(b)}{ln(a)+ln(b)}$

**Carry out the same analysis for $y$:**

$xln(a) = xyln(ab)$

$ln(a) = yln(ab)$

$ln(a) = y(ln(a) + ln(b))$

### $y = \frac{ln(a)}{ln(a)+ln(b)}$

**Add the two equations for $x$ and $y$ together:**

### $x + y = \frac{ln(b)}{ln(a) + ln(b)} + \frac{ln(a)}{ln(a) + ln(b)}$

Make one fraction with the common denominator,

### $x + y = \frac{ln(b) + ln(a)}{ln(a) + ln(b)} = \frac{ln(a) + ln(b)}{ln(a) + ln(b)}$

Since the numerator = denominator, it equates to $1$,

$$x + y = 1$$